# Passing either null or a string to a stored procedure doesn't work (because of quotes?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure below. For parameters called `LockedByName` and `LockedByLoginName` I want to pass either a string (which can contain spaces etc. - so I quote it with single quotes) or a NULL value.

The procedure works with strings but doesn't work with null value. I assume this is because it somehow silently fails because it cannot put the NULL value into quotes.

What could be the way to both keep the quotes and also keep the ability to use null value?

It similarly fails when the parameter is an empty string which would be fine to use too.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangeLockFormStatus] 
    @FormID as int,
    @LockedByName as nvarchar(50) = null,
    @LockedByLoginName as nvarchar(50) = null,
    @TableName as varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ActualTableName AS varchar(255)

    SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName   

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @ActualTableName 
        + ' SET LockedByName=''' + @LockedByName + ''','
        + 'LockedByLoginName=''' + @LockedByLoginName
        + ''' WHERE [ID] = ' + CAST(@FormID AS VARCHAR(25)) + ';'

    EXEC(@sql)
END
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *doesn't work with null value*.  Does the code fail, and return an error message?  Or do you see an unexpected result in your table?

Comment: @destination-data there is no error, but the values in the database table do not change.

Comment: A good way to see what is going on is to replace `EXEC(@sql)` with `PRINT @sql`.  I *suspect* the problem is you cannot concatenate nulls.  Null + anything results in a null.  Combining EXEC with a null variable doesn't result in an update or an error.  @Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer should fix these issues for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), you can continue to use your parameters directly, rather than having to mangle them into the string. Something like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangeLockFormStatus] 
    @FormID as int,
    @LockedByName as nvarchar(50) = null,
    @LockedByLoginName as nvarchar(50) = null,
    @TableName as varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ActualTableName AS varchar(255)

    SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName   

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @ActualTableName 
        + ' SET LockedByName=@LockedByName,'
        + 'LockedByLoginName=@LockedByLoginName'
        + ' WHERE [ID] = @FormID;'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
         N'@LockedByName nvarchar(50),@LockedByLoginName nvarchar(50),@FormID int',
         @LockedByName,@LockedByLoginName,@FormID
END
```